# Reinstall ubuntu in dual boot disk

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, boot-partition

I have installed 2 OS in my disk, first one is windows and the second one is ubuntu, I want to reinstall ubuntu and combine partitions however I'm not sure if I do it, it could cause some trouble.

Reason to combine free partitions is due to I need more free space for applications.

Comment: Without backups in case of a problem, you are sure to encounter a problem. See [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Backup to an external drive or to the cloud, then verify (checksums work well and rapidly) the backups mach the original; then make another backup to a different destination (external drive or cloud) and verify it, Once backups are made, please run _lsblk | grep -v loop  && df -h | grep -v loop|tempfs|_ so we can see what partitions are on your drives; highlight the resulting text, copy it as text, come back here, click [edit], and paste the resulting text into your question. Please don't use Add Comment as that scrambles the formatting of the info.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly resize using a application called 'gparted'.  It is available in a 'ISO' from the following URL --> https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/ .  I do not have any dual boot systems and certainly not with one being Windows but I have had great luck with it.  It is capable and I have had zero problems with it in Resizing and/or Enlarging Partitions.
I have for many years used this app by burning the Bootable ISO image to a CD. Recently I have put the image on a USB Thumb Drive.

I feel that it would work for you, given the Linux is after the Windows, on the drive.  This app is a great open source program.  As to what it might do to your Windows stuff I proffer no advice whatsoever.  It should not create any problems but not sure about the validation thingy ; - ))
Robert